# Cannot turn on "Assign new records created by Salesforce Sites guest user to a default owner in the org"

Tags: force.com-sites, admin

I'm trying to enable "[Assign new records created by Salesforce Sites guest user to a default owner in the org](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_assign_guest_records.htm&type=5)" in my org, but when I got to "develop -> sites", I don't even see the option to turn it on:

**What I expect to see:**

[image]

**What I actually see:**
[image]

What steps am I missing?

Comment: communities is NOT enabled in this org...  But if I open a brand new dev org, I still have the setting available, even though communities are not on...